# Are there editable grids and TreeView controls for sapui5?

Tags: sapui5

Are there editable grids and TreeView controls for sapui5? I checked the demo page and didn't see any.

Answer (score 0):

If by 'editable grids' you mean an Excel-like grid, there is none, but someone wrote a blog a while back on how to achieve something like that: http://scn.sap.com/community/developer-center/front-end/blog/2013/12/16/excel-like-custom-grid-control-in-sapui5-openui5

A tree-view control does exist, in the sap.ui.commons package: https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#test-resources/sap/ui/commons/demokit/Tree.html

Answer (score 0):

For an editable grid you could also use a table and insert a TextField control as template. In contrast to TextView control, with a TextField the content of a cell is editable.